# Meeting two conditions to display a column from another page

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

I'm attempting to meet two conditions so that I can display a column from one spreadsheet to another. The two conditions are that the date matches and that the persons' name matches. Once these two are met, a column that shows the employees reply from the page `Form Responses` would display onto another spreadsheet that's more compact.

```
=IF(and('Form Responses 1'!B2:B=A7,
        'Form Responses 1'!E2:E="John Smith"),
        'Form Responses 1'!F2:F," ")
```

`'Form Responses 1'!B2:B` would be the date from the first spreadsheet.
A7 would be the date in the compact spreadsheet

Comment: What do you mean by `B2:B`? Show us some of your data as example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this format:

```
=IF((AND(Form Responses 1!B2:B=A7,Form Responses 1!E2:E="John Smith")), Form Responses 1!F2:F,"")
```

Comment: No luck, nothing displays when I use this.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by B2:B?

Comment: Thats what the program gives me when I select the B column from the other page of the spreadsheet while creating the formula.

Answer (score 0):

**one cell solution:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS('Form Responses 1'!B2:B, "="&$A$7,
                          'Form Responses 1'!E2:E, "=John Smith"),
                          'Form Responses 1'!F2:F, " "))
```

Answer (score -1):

**per cell solution:**

```
=IF(AND('Form Responses 1'!B2=$A$7,
        'Form Responses 1'!E2="John Smith"),
        'Form Responses 1'!F2, " ")
```